# Composition of Dirac delta function with a function in two variables

Tags: analysis, physics, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

I have a Dirac delta function of two variables: $\delta(s-z_{1}(1-z_{1})-z_{2}(1-z_{2}))$ which I need to solve. I know how to solve when there is only one variable: $\delta(s-z(1-z))$, in which case I can write $\delta(g(z))=\sum_{i}\frac{\delta(z-z_{i})}{|g'(z_{i})|}$ where the sum extends over the roots of $g(z)$.
I don't know how to do the same for the two-variable case. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Properties_in_n_dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Properties_in_n_dimensions)

Comment: I found $\int_{{\mathbb R}^n} f(x)\delta(g(x)) dx = \int_{g^{-1}(0)}\frac{f(x)}{|\nabla g|} d\sigma(x)$ with a search engine. Some assumptions are needed on $g$. [Here is the link](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10652460412331270661)

Comment: Thanks, I had found those expressions myself also but I am really out of clue how that would work out here in this specific example.